Request with two proxies at same time in C#
I'm doing requests using authenticated proxy and works fine on localhost but on production mode not work because all request must be doing using other proxy and this proxy config replace the initial config.
Needed authenticated proxy
    WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy();
            proxy.Address = new Uri(Urlproxy);
            proxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = true;
            proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);
        
        
            handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            handler.Proxy = proxy;
            handler.UseProxy = true;
        
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler, true);
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new 
            MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        
            String response = httpClient.GetStringAsync(parametros).Result;
            httpClient.Dispose();
            return response;

Web.config (mandatory first proxy)
      <system.net>
        <defaultProxy enabled="true">
          <proxy usesystemdefault="True" proxyaddress="mandatoryProxy" bypassonlocal="True"/>
          <bypasslist>
            <add address="[a-z]+\.mydomain\.com"/>
          </bypasslist>
        </defaultProxy>
      </system.net>

I need call the second proxy (authenticated) throught the first proxy. Like this:
My server -> proxy1 -> proxy2 authenticated -> other server
Is this possible? How could configure two simultaneous proxies?
